# regex to find all instances of "),"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to find all instances of ")," to replaced with "), " using regex.

Comment: Would be good to show us any work or efforts that you already put to solve this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This work on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com)

This is the regex that you want

```
/(\),)/g
```

Comment: I don't think you want the `*` ... `(hello),(world)` becomes `), (), h), e), l), l), o), ), (), w), o), r), l), d), )),` :p

Comment: Thank you for noticing the closing operator. With "*" we find all occurrences (including consecutive occurrences) of the requested pattern. Example: 

Hiiii),wecandoit),),

In this case the last 2 are considered together as one pattern. If you want to take them individually, as suggested by @JaromandaX the * should be removed.

Comment: the `*` was completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

Regex: (\),)([^\s-])
Replace: ), $2

(),) : Will find all the strings ), in your text.  You need to escape the ) symbol as the ) symbol is a special character

([^\s-]) : In case you already have the ), + a space, you don't want 2 spaces, so we use the ^ not

In this example:
hello (world),(regex),(coding), (testing)
You will replace the ), after world and regex

**REPLACE**
$2 is needed to keep the first character of the next group/word

You can test it on https://regex101.com/